# Set different styles on a single element

Tags: javascript, css

Consider i have a text like `HELLO_WORLD`, and i am interested to set 2 different style style. For example, can i have **HEllo_** in green, and the **WORLD** in blue.

Since I load all the character once like HELLO_WORLD. **i am not interested to solutions like**

```
<div style=s1>HELLO_</div>
<div style=s2>WORLD</div>
```

What i am looking for is somthing like a function which gets a number, and set style1 to the letters before this character and apply the other style to the rest

```
 function  applyStyle(charracterNumber){

    //Apply style1 to chars before charracterNumber
   .
   .
   .  
 //Apply style2 to chars after charracterNumber

}
```

`charracterNumber` is an `integer`

Comment: Split the string (`string.split(characterNumber)`) at the number, wrap each string in a `<span style={styleNumber}>`, then add the strings together.

Comment: @pfkurtz can you write it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow isn't really the place to ask for other people to write code for you. RJM's answer below is correct. There's enough info here for you to fill out the rest of your function.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your comment, if you were just asking me to copy my comment as an answer below, but at this point @RJM has got it covered.

Answer (score 5):

Styles are applied to an HTML element, not to parts of the element or its content. So to apply different styles, you will need the content in different elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

There is an element in HTML called `span`.
It has no inherent meaning (no default style change).

You can put individual parts of a paragraph in a `span`.
It was made for setting different styles to different spans of text.
Put different parts of the text to set different styles to each one.

For your code, use this:

```html
<div><span style="color:green">HELLO_</span><span style="color:blue">WORLD</span>
</div>
```